# Find resource name for text input box and button fields for react native android app

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to use the pre-launch report offered by the play store to run my app on different devices. My app requires a sign-in and the pre-launch report supports providing sign-in credentials in advance so that the test framework can sign in during the test. It requires me to fill the following form
[image]

I don't know how to find the resource name for the text input fields for username and password and sign-in button on the sign-in page. Please let me know if there is a way to either find resource names or specify a resource name for such fields for an Android app built using React Native

Comment: **Varun Gupta**, did you found a solution how to set that id ?
as I understand 'mID' that was describe bellow - this is not what we need.

Comment: @Kholiavko I was able to get around the problem in a different way and didn't look at it further.

Comment: Can you share you solution please ? I

Comment: @Kholiavko I just created a separate APK which has the login information hard-coded.

Comment: Thanks, interested solution, but what about "Log in" button, how it pressed it ? Or you create onBlur event for field ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try Layout Inspector in android studio.

1. Run your app in Emulator.
2. Go to tools > Andriod > Layout inspector and Select your app's process.

Now you can get id of each view. it will be with property name "mID". Check the screenshot below:

[image]

**EDIT**
FYI: This is a very old answer which worked initially. It may not work now. So just try this solution. If it doesn't work and you find perfect solution please post a new answer or edit this answer or add link to that answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: React-Native view ids are generating at runtime. you can not find static resource id to use at Google Play Store Pre-Launch Report

Comment: Relevant Github issue: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/9777

Comment: This answer no longer works as of March 2019: the Pre-launch report Credentials form rejects these mIDs with a "Field can not contain any spaces or special characters except underscores" message. Example mID: id/0x6AD. Just entering 0x6AD or 6AD fails with the same message.

Comment: Hi @NicolasConnault thanks for reporting this. I will add this warning in the answer. But Sorry, I can't find the correct way to do it right now. It would be really greate if you find the solution and post it here so that I can give the link to that answer here.

Comment: @AnkitAggarwal sorry I haven't found the solution yet, I'm trying to get the pre-launch report to work on my expokit app, and it's just not working at all... It's probably a bug we should report to Google.

Comment: I got the error message "Field can not contain any spaces or special characters except underscores". So I replaced the forward slash with an underscore. Result: `id/0x85` -> `id_0x85`.
Now I wait for Google's crawlers to accept this.

Comment: @GunnarK did that work for you? if not, did you find a solution?

Comment: @Programonks unfortunately I forgot to check up on my changes.. Also cannot find them in Pre-launch's history..